# PDO fetchAll method undefined

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting error "Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll()" with he following code:

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$conn->exec($sql);

$results = $conn->fetchAll();
print_r($results);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I think I am missing something obvious but can't find it, any ideas?
Regards.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/pdostatement.fetchall.php) of _PDOStatement_::fetchAll?

Comment: I did, but then I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for some reason you are missing usage example from the manual page.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

**Try This Code**